# best method for background uploader in Android

Tags: android

Problem:

I want to write a process that will allow a user to take photos with the device and for those photos to then be uploaded to some listener in the cloud.  The user should not have to do anything to initiate the upload, a background listener would just watch the folder and as long as it finds files in it it would upload them and delete them.

Two problems:
1) how to keep the program running in the background even after the user is no longer taking pictures (and if they reboot the device for it to wake up and finish the uploads, if any remain)

2) assuming the connection is spotty (as it always is) how to verify that a given image has completed its upload, and if not, to resubmit it.

I don't need any code examples, I just would like opinions on the best strategy to get this implemented.

I was going to use Apache commons and just do an upload to a PHP, but am not sure what sort of error checking exists to take into account a connection drop mid file.

TIA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having essentially written this application several times on several platforms, I can tell you that it's not a trivial endeavor.  To tackle the first problem, you can create a Service that sits in the background and performs your uploads.  In order for it to start up automatically, you can declare that it receives the intent android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED in your manifest (you'll need the permission android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED in order to make use of that).  If you're going to listen for stuff written out by the standard camera app, you can use [registerContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver%28android.net.Uri,%20boolean,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29) to listen for new stuff - beware, phones can have more than one place they stash photos!

For the second problem, have your webservice return information regarding the completion of the upload which your client can use to decide on retries.

Comment: fabulously useful advice... I'll probably give you the checkmark, but will leave it open for a bit to see if anyone else chimes in with stuff I can think about (people generally stop looking after a question has been answered).  As for where the files are being written to, I was going to write the files myself to the sdcard... is that going to present a problem?

Comment: "To tackle the first problem, you can create a Service that sits in the background and performs your uploads." -- However, you absolutely positively do NOT want to design this such that the service is supposed to live forever. Use an `IntentService`, so that the upload occurs on a background thread (required) and so that the service automatically shuts down when there are no more uploads to be done. Use `startService()` to send the command to the `IntentService` to have it initiate the upload.

Comment: Yes, a thousand times yes to the IntentService.  You would not believe the number of ways that you can screw something like this up if you try and manage your background operation yourself.

Comment: what if the photo app is no longer running? what starts the intent service then?  My concern is that there may be situations where the photo app is finished being used and the device is tossed in bag, but it still has to offload whatever has not been successfully offloaded.

Comment: Having done this in a commercial application using the ContentObserver technique I mentioned here, there were no problems with the OS killing it.  Note that the Intent Service would be used for the uploading - your other service discovers the photo and throws an Intent over to the upload service to actually push it up to the server.  That keeps the content observing service very lightweight and easy to maintain with an easy lifecycle, and the Intent Service lives just to upload stuff.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to write a process that will
>   allow a user to take photos with the
>   device and for those photos to then be
>   uploaded to some listener in the
>   cloud.

Please either initiate the picture-taking yourself (so you know when it is time to upload) or create an `ACTION_SEND` `Activity` to plug into the camera app's Share option, so the user can upload that way.

> The user should not have to do
>   anything to initiate the upload, a
>   background listener would just watch
>   the folder and as long as it finds
>   files in it it would upload them and
>   delete them.

Please don't.

A major complaint among Android users are apps written using this sort of technique -- some "background listener" that is taking up RAM and delivering no value 99.999% of the time. The core Android team has been forced to modify the OS to prevent developers from screwing up users' phones this way. Newer versions of Android will terminate your "background listener" after a while. Users may terminate your "background listener" sooner than that, using a "task killer" or the Manage Services screen in the Settings app.

Please either initiate the picture-taking yourself (so you know when it is time to upload) or create an `ACTION_SEND` `Activity` to plug into the camera app's Share option, so the user can upload that way.

Comment: A couple comments - first, taking the picture yourself won't actually allow you to take a full resolution photo on all handsets, despite the docs.  On some phones, it gives you a reduced quality image no matter what you do.  As for the background operation, you absolutely need to have a setting so that users can disable the content listener, or you will (rightly) get a lot of complaints about it.

Comment: @jjb: "On some phones, it gives you a reduced quality image no matter what you do" -- got a roster of affected devices?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have access to the notes that we made on different models, as I'm not longer with that company.  I seem to remember the assorted Hero variants doing it, along with the Eris.  It's possible the Evo 4G was among that group - it seemed to be a problem with SenseUI.  It's possible that since I'm no longer actively working on that app that it's been corrected in more recent builds of SenseUI, I can't answer that.  But I thought it was worthing bringing up as a potential issue.  Oh, another fun per-phone quirk:  some phones will put your picture in the gallery, even if you...

Comment: ...don't want them to.  But some won't ever put your picture in the gallery, so you have the fun choice of either doubling up on some handsets or missing the gallery on some handsets, if you want the photos you take to end up there.  Tons of fun!  For the most part, the ill-behaved handsets were lower end handsets, especially ones that had been heavily customized.  I know the first CLIQ had problems and the Droid Eris had problems.  I'm hoping most of those problems will rotate out.

Comment: "Newer versions of Android will terminate your background listener after a while." ....  So, what's the workaround? This is a custom application (not for the market, nor for public distribution) so, while I totally appreciate the advice not to auto upload, that's actually a principal requirement.  Should (and can) the app test to see if the listener is running and re-start it if Android kills it? The photos HAVE to get to the server... that's the whole point of the application. If the listener is turned off by the OS, what do I do?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: "So, what's the workaround?" -- use an `IntentService` and `AlarmManager` to check for new photos periodically, ideally with a user-configurable polling period.

Comment: I haven't observed that the system killed the background service of the application I used to work on.  I last worked on it about four or five months ago, but the background uploading part of it worked fine (this is the background upload feature of Photobucket's Android app).

Comment: @jjb: Android, with each passing OS release, is getting more and more aggressive about terminating services that have remained in memory too long, in response to the wave of user complaints. Ms. Hackborn has discussed this many times on the `android-developers` Google Group.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Sure, I've read that, I was just saying that in the time that I worked on an application that essentially performed this exact task (as a user option that could be turned on and off, I'll note), we didn't ever observe our service getting killed by the OS, even during long burn-in testing runs.  Perhaps that will change going forward, I can't say, but I hadn't yet noticed any tightening of things.  This was up through 2.2.